# Copying only files which have another file as a sibling [based on extension]?

Tags: ant

I am trying to use ANT to copy some files of a C++ build into another directory.

The output of the build looks like this:

```
/Build
   /LibA
      LibA.lib
      LibA.pdb
   /LibB
      LibB.lib
      LibB.pdb
   /ProjA
      myexe.exe
      myexe.pdb
   /Foo
      foo.exe
      foo.pdb
   /...
```

Now, I would like to copy all `*.exe` files and their `*.pdb` files to another directory (but not the `*.pdb` files of the libs).

I tried with:

```
<copy todir="outdir">
   <fileset dir="Build">
      <include name="**/*.exe" />
      <include name="**/*.pdb" />
   </fileset>
</copy>
```

However, then I will also get the `*.pdb` files inside the LibA, LibB, ... folders.

Is there any way I can only copy the pdb-files which have an `*.exe`-file in the same directory as their sibling?
Unfortunately, the folders are not named in any way that would allow using wildcards based on the folder name.

Of course, I could list each file individually, such as:

```
<include name="ProjA/*.pdb" />
<include name="Foo/*.pdb" />
<!-- ... -->
```

However, I am thinking that maybe there is an elegant way where I can specify "copy all `*.exe` files and all `*.pdb` files which have an `*.exe` file next to them".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`<present>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#presentselect) selector to find the "sibling" files, something like this:

```
<copy todir="outdir">
  <fileset dir="Build" includes="**/*.pdb">
    <present targetdir="Build">
      <mapper type="glob" from="*.pdb" to="*.exe" />
    </present>
  </fileset>
  <fileset dir="Build" includes="**/*.exe" />
  <flattenmapper />
</copy>
```

This will only copy the .pdb files with matching .exe files.

To keep it simple, use a separate fileset for the exe files.

The flatten mapper is only needed if you want to copy just the files ignoring the directory structure in the source.